Shopify App Block Schema: "target" Property Not Valid According to VS Code Extension
I'm working on a Shopify app and according to the official documentation, the app block schema should support properties like target, stylesheet, and javascript. However, when I try to use these properties, the VS Code Shopify Liquid extension flags them as invalid.

The extension throws an error saying the target property is not valid. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there something I'm missing or is there an update needed for the extension?
Any help would be appreciated!

Inconsistent guidelines from official Shopify documents::





This issue is most probably an extension issue rather than a Shopify issue. I think their extension needs more maintenance.
What exactly happened here is:
The liquid extension is treating this code block as a theme file code and treating it that way. Shopify theme sections don't support those properties. That's why you're given those warnings for using those properties.
So, if you run your code, it should function correctly as the official documentation supports them.
My recommendation:
1. Ignore the warnings and keep building.
2. Report this issue to Shopify's theme extension page.

Thank you for your response, but I discovered in the theme-check documentation that such tags are no longer allowed for app blocks as of Shopify CLI version 3. As you can see, it contradicts the app blocks documentation, which states that app blocks must contain a target schema attribute.
You can find the AppBlockValidTags rule documentation here: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefronts/themes/tools/theme-check/checks/app-block-valid-tags.
